Serilog File Name Include Domain Name
How can i add Domain name as a part of my Serilog file
The start up code is like below on Startup.cs file
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  SerilogConfig.Configure(services, Configuration);
    ....................
    --------------
}

And the code of SerilogConfig is like
  public class SerilogConfig
  {
      public static LoggingLevelSwitch? MyLoggingLevelSwitch { get; set; }
      
      public static void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, IConfiguration configuration)
      {
          var baseLogPath = configuration["SeriLog:LogPath"];
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(baseLogPath))
          {
              throw new Exception("SeriLog:LogPath is not set in the app.settings.");
          }

          var logLevel = configuration["SeriLog:LogLevel"];
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(logLevel))
          {
              throw new Exception("SeriLog:LogLevel is not set in the app.settings.");
          }

          var deploymentMode = configuration["DeploymentMode"];
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(deploymentMode))
          {
              throw new Exception("DeploymentMode is not set in the app.settings.");
          }

          var appName = configuration["ApplicationName"];
          if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(appName))
          {
              throw new Exception("ApplicationName is not set in the app.settings.");
          }

          var rollbarAccessToken = configuration["RollbarAccessToken"];
          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rollbarAccessToken))
          {
              throw new Exception("RollbarAccessToken is not set in the web.config.");
          }

          var appLogName = $"{appName}-{deploymentMode.ToLower()}";
          var detailedLogFile = baseLogPath + "\\" + appLogName + $"-{DateTime.Now:yyyy-MM-dd}.log";

          var outputTemplate = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] <" + deploymentMode + "|{SourceContext}|{CorrelationId}> {Message}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}";
          
          -----------------
          --------------------
          ------------------------
          
      }
  }

I can add the domain name / application name as a part of appsettings.json file, but in my case the website is hosted on IIS in a different way
There are 2 different websites exists in IIS , both of them pointing to the same directory / same appsettings.json file . Only the domain mapping is different.
So sites www.site1.com  and www.site2.com is pointing to the same folder in IIS
So is there any way I can add the domain name / part of the domain name [ site1  / site2 ] to my Serilog log file

You can use the "Serilog.Enrichers" and use '.Enrich.WithAssemblyName()' which will print the assemblyname in the log.

@ChinmayT But in my case AssemblyName might be the same. Since as i explained, my 2 sites www.site1.com and site.com , referring to the same folder

Ok, I understand. You can add "DomainName" into Appsettings.json and read it from configuration["DomainName"] and append it to the Serilog file name. let me know if this is all you want to do. I will answer with a sample code.

Two websites shares same appsettings file. So this approach will not work. In question i explained this and the sample code already read appsettings values

Based on information provided, To get the IIS Site name you need use "HostingEnviroment.ApplicationHost.GetSiteName():" This will give you the site name of the current request and use that to build different serilog files

Having two different site they both will have their unique site and site id. This will help you to get the current site name of the request and will help you to log different logs files for different site requests.
